# change UIBarButtonItem style

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I create UIBarButtonItem  using

```
UIBarButtonItem *previous = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:@"Search"
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(SearchAction:)];
```

how to change its style to black

best regards

Comment: it will automatically take the navigationbar color..

Comment: if you want black button then just set your navigation bar tintcolor to black color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the tint color of UINavigationBar to black.